# Visual studio 2013 auto complete for project files

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, autocomplete

My directory structure seems to be messing up the auto-complete for project created files. Here's a hierarchical representation (The project is called "Asdf"):

```
Asdf
  src
    Asdf (Contains the source files for the project.)
    SDL (Contains include files for SDL.)
  vc (Contains the actual visual studio solution file and configuration files.)
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Additional note: Project files are included in Project Properties->Include Directories. The Visual studio 2013 is the software in question.

Comment: "messing up" - can you be a *little* more precise in what that *means* ? When in doubt, (1) shut down vs, (2) delete your solution `.sdf` file, (3) start up vs, (4) reopen your solution. (5) let it index the source/include base *completely*. Then try again.

Comment: Well when I type "#include "<filename>" it doesn't auto-complete. Anyway thanks for the suggestion, I'll try it next time I have available.